# Linux FTP: Operation now in progress after restart/put

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp

I'm trying to transfer a 17 GB file on a rather slow connection. Over night, my SSH session appeared to time out, which interrupted the process at 11 GB and I am trying to restart it from there. What I get is

```
ftp> Connect, dir change etc...
250 OK. Current directory is /domains/gallery/ftp
ftp> restart 11460055532 <-- amount of bytes I managed to transfer
Restarting at 11460055532 for next get, put or append
ftp> put gallery_data.tar.bz2
local: gallery_data.tar.bz2 remote: gallery_data.tar.bz2
229 Extended Passive mode OK (|||34643|)
ftp: local: gallery_data.tar.bz2: Operation now in progress
ftp>
```

Nothing more is displayed, and nothing appears to happen in the background.

I really hope someone has a tip or I've wasted another 24 hours - Thank you!

Comment: I suspect there might be a file lock issue locally maybe? That's the only thing I can associate with the "Operation now in progress".

Comment: Very few replies; so I have now split the source file and the portion of the destination, then transferred the remaining split files and cat them all together on the destination. That relieves the urgency of receiving a reply, but I'd still be interested if there are any ideas of why that might have happened...

Answer (score 0):

For timeout issue, you have to do these thing.

1. you have to increase the data connection time in /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
   data_connection_timeout=360 or more.
2. You'll also need to load the nf_conntrack_ftp kernel module to allow the random ports that ftp uses to be opened for you.

Comment: There is no timeout. It's simply that the transfer after restart does not start on a large file. The same procedure does well work if the file is smaller, e.g. a few 100 KB or 1 GB etc